# Validating array of input fields in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-template-form

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/VvpKgaURmgVivIdUbJ3I?p=preview) I have an Angular form that contains one input field followed by an array of input fields. I need to validate that any of these fields is not empty.

The single field works well, but I'm struggling with validating the array of fields, I'm getting an error `Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!` when the form is displayed. Any ideas how to fix the plunk attempt?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <form #f="ngForm" name="form" (ngSubmit)="ok(f.form)" novalidate>
       <input name="singleField" id="singleField" [(ngModel)]="field1"  
              #singleField="ngModel" required />
       <div *ngIf="singleField.touched || submitted" class="errorMsg">
            <label *ngIf="singleField.control.hasError('required')">
                Field is required
            </label>
       </div>
       <br/><br/>
       <div *ngFor="let field2 of manyFields; let i = index">
           <input name="field" id="field" [(ngModel)]="field2"  
                  #field="ngModel" required />
           <div *ngIf="field.touched || submitted" class="errorMsg">
                <label *ngIf="field.control.hasError('required')">
                    Field is required
                </label>
           </div>
       </div>
       <br/><br/>
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .errorMsg {
      color: red;
    }
  `]
})
export class App {

       field1: string = 'delete this';
       manyFields: string[] = ['Field 1', 'Field 2', 'Field 3'];

       ok(form: any){
            if (form.valid)
                 alert("Form is valid");
            else     
                 alert("Form is NOT valid");
       }
}
```

Comment: that mean all fields in `manyFields` are required ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable` error because  `[(ngModel)]="field2"` you can't assaign `field2`

this solve the error and make the `required` validation work

```
<input [name]="field2" [id]="field2" ngModel #field="ngModel" required />
```

I have use the value of `field` from name and id attribute.

validate dynamic fields

```
  manyFieldsValidators(form: any) {
    let fields: string[] = [];

    if (form && form.value) {
      for (let f of this.manyFields) {
        if (form.value[f] === '') {
          fields.push(f)
        } 
      } 
    }

    if (fields.length > 0) {
      return { fields: true, message: `${fields.join(',')} are empty` }
    } else {
      return { fields: false, message: '' }
    }

  }
```

template

```
    <div class="errorMsg" *ngIf="manyFieldsValidators(f).fields">
        {{manyFieldsValidators(f).message}}
    </div>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-from)

> template form is meant for simple form ,validation can be done in more cleaner way by reactive form `Form Array` you may consider to use `reactive form`